# How can I change logo from phonegap build

Tags: android, xml, cordova, phonegap-build, phonegap-desktop-app

I created app from phonegap desktop. How can I change its default logo for android and windows.
Screen at build.phonegap.com says 
Your application's details are bound to the config.xml file in your application package. To edit these details, change that file and push it back up to us.

you can see brief info about my problem.
http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/how-can-i-change-logo-of-my-app-it-showing-default-icon

Comment: Have you tried to change the xml file?

Comment: No actually I don't know what to edit ?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try to build your project and then go to YourApp/platforms/android
and there you can see the `AndroidManifest.xml`. Inside the file there is a line:

`<application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true">`

As you can see the icons are in drawable/icon, so you have to go to res/drawable and you just have to change the icon.png.

Then you have to rebuild your app so the changes take place.

**Note:** there are different drawable folder inside the res folder, you can change all off them if you want. Some of them are the splash screen.

Let me know if that works :)